# Java Applet Graphics Resizing

Tags: java, math, applet

So I've got an assignment that takes two inputs, males and females, and outputs matingPairs, the product of the two.

In addition to that, the instructions ask to draw a shape using one of those variables.

I've decided to draw circles for each value.

I first draw matingPairs, followed by the smaller male and female circles on top of the original, larger matingPairs circle.

The problem I'm running in to is obviously representing the graphic in the applet.  If the numbers go higher than say 100, the graphic becomes too large for the applet.

I'm looking for a way to basically have the matingPairs circle always fill the applet, then have males and females dynamically adjust so their size is scaled relative to the matingPairs circle size.  I'm using JApplet.

Thank you very much for any guidance.  I'm really looking for a solution, rather a push in the right direction.

Comment: F*** yea, I'm also looking for people to do my homework as well.

Comment: The homework is done.  This is extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should provide more instruction about how are you drawing the circles in the `Graphics` object.
The idea is to manage two bi-dimensional spaces with different scales; the first one is the input data and the second one represents the available area to draw such data. The first one can have data on any location, such `(5, 5)`, `(0.2, 0.3)`or `(1200, 3400)`. The key is to map the original coordinates of the first space into the second, using the proper transformation: scale + translation.
This transformation must be calculated prior to start drawing and applies to any point drawn.
The idea is to map the rectangle where input data resides to the available area in the graphics. If the graphics area is 200x200 pixels and the data could be from `(0, 0)` to `(400, 400)`, just divide by 2 the coordinates of the points to draw. If the original data is not centered in `(0, 0)`, use a translation.

Comment: So I need to calculate the translation before drawing, then apply that to each circle.

Answer (score 1):

So, do you need to know how to get the size of the applets canvas or how to scale the male/female circles accordingly?

Edit:

Drawing a circle to fill the 600x600 area should be easy. Just keep in mind that you often specify the top left corner of the circle and the width and height (i.e. the diameter) when calling drawOval() / fillOval() or similar methods.

The next question is: what does represent the size of the input (males/females) and output (pairs), the area or the radius of the circles? Whatever it is, it should be easy to calculate the input/output ratio and then multiply the fixed size of the output circle with it in order to get the size of the input circle.

Comment: I'd like to keep the applet size to something like 600x600 so it plays nice in a browser, so scaling the circles would be what I'm after.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense to me.  So I basically need to figure out what the ratio of matingPairs is compared to the static representation, then multiply males and females by that.  Got it.  Thanks.